# Braodcastreceiver crashes the program

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to pass an object to `Broadcastreceiver`.
The mechanism works well without passing any data, but when I try to pass an object, the program crashes.

This is the code:

```
public void SetFutureStartTime(int startHour, int startMin)
{
    Context context = this;

    m_alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver_BoilerOn.class);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("tcpClientObj",(Serializable)m_TcpClient);
    intent.putExtra("DATA",args);

    m_alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0); // --------------> The code crushes here

    // Set the alarm to start at 21:32 PM
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMin);

    m_alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), m_alarmIntent);
}
```

This is the `Broadcastreceiver` implementation:

```
public class AlarmReceiver_BoilerOn extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("DATA");
    final TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient) args.getSerializable("tcpClientObj");  
}
}
```

This is the error log:

> ```
> 11-19 19:35:59.553: D/AndroidRuntime(2389): Shutting down VM
> 11-19 19:35:59.553: D/AndroidRuntime(2389): --------- beginning of crash
> 11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): Process: boiler.boiler, PID: 2389
> 11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
> ```
>
> serializable object (name = boiler.boiler.TcpClient)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1526)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1474)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1392)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8655)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3052)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at boiler.boiler.MainActivity.SetFutureStartTime(MainActivity.java:414)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at boiler.boiler.MainActivity$2$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:185)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   boiler.boiler.MainActivity$ConnectTask$1
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1521)
>       11-19 19:35:59.571: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):   ... 31 more
>       11-19 19:35:59.590: W/ActivityManager(1590):   Force finishing activity boiler.boiler/.MainActivity

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If m_TcpClient implements Parcelable interface, your best option is to pass its instance as an Parcelable via the intent Extras. You don't have to cast it to Serializable or Parcelable explicetly.
However, keep in mind, that there is a well-known bug with the AlarmManager. It loses the parcelable extras, so instead of passing it directly, you'll have to marshall the data first. Here are some basic methods of doing it:

```
fun Parcelable.marshall() : ByteArray {
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    writeToParcel(parcel, 0)
    val bytes = parcel.marshall()
    parcel.recycle()
    return bytes
}

fun <T> ByteArray.unmarshall(creator: Parcelable.Creator<T>): T {
    val parcel = unmarshall()
    val result = creator.createFromParcel(parcel)
    parcel.recycle()
    return result
}

private fun ByteArray.unmarshall(): Parcel {
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    parcel.unmarshall(this, 0, size)
    parcel.setDataPosition(0)
    return parcel
}
```

Using this methods, you can put ByteArray as an intent extra

```
intent.putExtra(Receiver.EXTRA, m_TcpClient.marshall())
```

and then get it in the BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
intent.getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA)?.run {
    val m_TcpClient = unmarshall(TcpClient.CREATOR)
}
```